# dictionary seperation in python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a question that might end up being a fairly simple fix but i am having a lot of trouble with it. I am making a program that will allow the user to pick between a list of text files that are all like this

to search:mirar,buscar

to play:jugar

to be:ser,estar

to run:correr

to make:hacer

to talk:hablar

to take:tomar

to study:estudiar

to arrive:llegar

to practice:practicar

this is the exact format for all of them and i am supposed to put these into a dictionary as key value pairs to make a sort of quiz and ive managed to do that part however i am running into a couple of problems. one is that some of these such as **to search** for example have multiple correct answers and i dont know how to assign multiple different values to the same key or if thats even possible. and the second problem is that the values have \n on the ends of them and i dont know how to remove that. and even if i did, the keys with two options only have the \n on the second value.

```
import os
import sys

def file_open():
    file_list=[]
    contents=os.listdir()
    for i in contents:
            
        if '.txt' in i.lower():
            file_list.append(i)
    if file_list==[]:
        sys.exit('Error')    
    print('file list:',
          file_list)
    
    input_file=str(input('enter the input file to use from the ones above'))    
    while True:
        try:
            file=open(input_file,'r')
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('FileNotFoundError')
            

    return file

def file_read():
    dictionary={}
    for line in file:
        (key,val)=line.split(':')
        dictionary[key]=val


        
        
    return(dictionary)
```

this is all of the code that i have written out so far and i would appreciate any help or even general advice. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You've properly identified the component techniques of your program.  Each of those is covered quite well in existing Stack Overflow answers and elsewhere on line.  Search out each of those individually, and work through the examples or tutorials one by one.

Comment: I am asking this question because I have already tried doing what you have proposed and have not been able to find anything pertaining to this particular problem on my own. If you could point me towards some resources I would appreciate it but I do not have an infinite amount of time to finish this and cannot spend any more hours than i already have looking through forums for an answer.

Comment: Not really the main issue, but you have a loop that will run forever if the file you try to open doesn't exist. Did you perhaps mean to put the `input(...)` (which doesn't need to be wrapped in `str()`; it's always a `str`) inside the `while`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store answers of each key into a list, for example:

```
query_answer={
      'to search':['mirar','buscar'],
      'to play':['jugar'],
      'to be':['ser','estar'],...}
```

Before process the values you should remove '\n':

```
def file_read(file):
    dictionary={}
    for line in file:
        (key,val)=line.split(':')
        val = val.rstrip("\n")
        dictionary[key] = val.split(',')
    return dictionary
```

Comment: `[a for a in vals]` is completely pointless when `vals` is already a `list` (and if it weren't a `list`, you'd just call the `list()` constructor, not execute a no-op `list` comprehension). Just remove the last three lines of the loop and replace them with `dictionary[key] = val.split(',')`

Comment: Thank you this was incredibly helpful and it also helped clear some of the problems I have been having understanding dictionaries as an added bonus. I appreciate your help very much sir.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thank you. I have removed the last three lines.